# PyCharm: 'unresolved reference' for 'object', 'isinstance', and more

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm with python 2.7

PyCharm shows 'Unresolved reference' for stuff that I beleive are keywords or part of the Python language. For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass
```

PyCharm will claim that 'object' is an 'Unresolved reference', showing the error mark. Similarely, 'isinstance' and many other built in method seems to be unresolved.

EDIT:
I appears that the problem is with the definition of the Python interpreter. In order to be able to submit the IML file (where the path to the Interpreter is stored), I've created my own python interpreter setting, called it 'MyPython', and set it to point to the interpreter on the machine. This interpreter does NOT have the path in the name (as it differs between machines), and it is not the one automatically created by PyCharm.
I'm seeing this behaviour only when I'm on MyPython. When on the one generated by PyCharm, that is: 'Python 2.7.8 (C:\Python27\python.exe)' parsing is fine. Looks like a bug in PyCharm?

Comment: are you sure you have set the proper interpreter for the project? (in Pycharm 4 is it here: Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter)

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko, take a look at my EDIT. Is it a bug in PyCharm? Do you know where I can report?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue with PyCharm 5.0.4. I completely recreate a project with a new virtualenv with Python 2.7.11 and the same trivial `class MyClass(object)` gives me an error mark. If I "run" from PyCharm, the code runs fine. I have correctly selected the right virtualenv in preferences.

Comment: Bug still present, PyCharm 2016.3.3, python2 interpreter.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865989/unresolved-attribute-reference-objects-for-class-in-pycharm