# Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class '' in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I use community pycharm and the version of python is 3.6.1, django is 1.11.1. This warning has no affect on running, but I cannot use the IDE's auto complete.

Answer (score 185):

You need to enable Django support. Go to

> **PyCharm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django**

and then check *`Enable Django Support`*

Comment: Django is only currently supported in the paid version of pycharm

Comment: @EricBlum yep, i know, but PyCharm is awesome. And there is a way to disable such inspections. There is also a way to use different IDEs, such as Atom, Visual Code and others.

Comment: @vishes_shell if i just disable this inspection, the auto complete will be also disable. is there some other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: @vishes_shell The question was about the Community Edition. I believe the correct answer is that it can not be done.

Comment: In version 4.5 of PyCharm is Django/objects supported in the community version.

Comment: Working like a charm +1

Comment: @Jon I'm on the latest version of PyCharm Community and I see in the IDE: `Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'MyClass' `

Answer (score 49):

You can also expose the default model manager explicitly:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: I do this because I have a custom `models.Manager()` and it has the added benefit of not breaking PyCharm CE. Is exposing the default model manager un-pythonic?

Comment: You can add multiple managers to your model. When you access Foo.objects you do access the standard manager so it is not incorrect to expose it. Whether it is un-pythonic, I am not sure.

Comment: I think the correct syntax would be `from django.db import models` now.

Comment: @FarzadSoltani thanks for flagging, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 22):

Use a Base model for all your models which exposes objects:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Model1(BaseModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Model2(BaseModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Will this affect migration adding another model?

Comment: No, because the class is basically the same, you better make the BaseModel abstract though. updating my answer

Answer (score 7):

You can try install  [django-stubs](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs)

```
pip install django-stubs
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33619366)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. This is a package reference in pypi for types
This package contains type stubs and a custom mypy plugin to provide more precise static types and type inference for Django framework. Django uses some Python "magic" that makes having precise types for some code patterns problematic. This is why we need this project. The final goal is to be able to get precise types for most common patterns.

Comment: It's the only way I was able to solve the situation in IntelliJ IDEA (2022 and 2023 paid editions). Unfortunately, because I would have expected IDEA to provide the same features than the PyCharm's paid version.

Answer (score 5):

In **pycharm professional** you can do that:

*PyCharm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django*

and then check *Enable Django Support*

If you are using **pycharm community** you can do it;

add models.Manager() at your objects model propery

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
```

additionally you can use pip install django-stubs

Answer (score 3):

Python Frameworks (Django, Flask, etc.) are only supported in the Professional Edition.
Check the link below for more details.

[PyCharm Editions Comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found this hacky workaround using stub files:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Model(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SomeModel(Model):
    pass
```

models.pyi

```
from django.db import models

class Model:
    objects: models.Manager()
```

This should enable PyCharm's code completion:
[image]

This is similar to Campi's solution, but avoids the need to redeclare the default value

Comment: Nice workaround, but better if it is located in a separate file. Like this, PyCharm wants every class specified in the stub, otherwise you'll get the Error "Cannot find reference 'SomeModel' in 'models.pyi' " when importing SomeModel in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution i found is putting @python_2_unicode_compatible decorator on any model.
It also requires you to have a **str** implementation four your function

For example:

```
# models.py

from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = Models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyCharm Community, you can ignore it in your settings: go to "Settings/Editor/Inpections/Unresolved references"

And then in "Options/Ignored references" add this line, replacing the name of your project. This will get rid of this warning. Ignoring this has had no negative effects for me.

```
<name of your project>.models.*
```

Answer (score -1):

**2024** solution (tested in Pycharm Pro):

PyCharm -> Files -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django

and check Enable Django Support.