# class has no object error with django and python

Tags: python, django

I am using Django .

Can anyone please check what's the error in here :
I keep getting an error in my view.py "Class Rate has no objects member"
This is views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Rate


def index(request):
    context = {
    "rates":Rate.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request,"rates/index.html", context)
```

and this is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Rate(models.Model):
    ratename=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    hourlyrate=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ratename} - {self.hourlyrate}"
```

Comment: You did not define another manager on the `Rate` model? Are you sure you imported the correct model?

Comment: If it's an actual error when you run the code, then please show the full traceback. If it's just a warning from your editor, then you can safely ignore it, or search for how to fix it for your editor (e.g. [here are instructions for PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865989/unresolved-attribute-reference-objects-for-class-in-pycharm)).