# How to do a query from a schema table with the Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-schema

I have a database that contains several schemas. I connected a model I made to a schema and when I do the registration from the Django administration page, everything is okay.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name", max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(db_column="description")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sch_test"."tb_data'
        verbose_name_plural = "MyModel"
```

Now I would like to make a simple query to retrieve the data from this schema via Django's ORM, but when I write :

```
instances = MyModel.objects.all()
```

The "objects" is underlined in red and I get the following message when I hover:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'MyModel'

That's where I'm stuck. Please the way to make ORM queries on schemas is different?
Need help please!

Answer (score 0):

Is the execution of your code also affected or is it just the message in the IDE? If it's only the IDE, this could solve your problem: [Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class '' in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865989/unresolved-attribute-reference-objects-for-class-in-pycharm)

In particular, if you are using the community version of PyCharm, you should to take a look at the second and third answer.